# How do I combine scopes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

If I have 2 scopes for Product class, I can do like this.

```
Product.best.sale #retrieves best and sale
```

For some reason, I have 2 seperated scopes like the following.

```
a = Product.best
b = Product.sale
a.b #ERROR
```

I tried a.b and it gives an error.

How do I combine a and b to get the Product.best.sale?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: these are not scopes, see here for doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html

Comment: This isn't counter-intuitive. I don't know Ruby or Rails, but I'd expect the last two lines not two work. Now, if `a = Product.best; b = a.sale` doesn't work, *that* would be contrary to semantics of most lanugages.

Comment: this is actually something Arel should do, but they haven't quite got it right. The syntax, though, would be like this. `a = Product.best; b = Product.sale; best_sale_scope = a & b`. Namely you can take 2 arel scopes, and the intersection of them, is the combination of their conditions (assuming they're on the same model)

Comment: Matthew Ruby's answer solved my problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When assigning `b`, you should be chaining the scope onto `a`, not a new `Product` call:

```
a = Product.best
b = a.sale
a.b
# => Retrieves best and sale
```